# How can i get generated id (to set "for" attribute) using MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, binding, view, label

```
@Html.CheckboxFor(m -> m.List[0].Value) // Value is bool property
```

generates something like this:

```
<input id="List_0__Value" name="List[0].Value" type="checkbox" value="false" />
```

How can i get the **generated id** of `m.List[0].Value` property, in order to assign it to "for" attribute?

```
<label for="List_0__Value">My Text</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.List[0].Value)
```

that will generate a "for" attribute for "label"

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just use LabelFor in the same way as you're doing CheckboxFor.